# Aggregating data, left aligned in R

Tags: r

I have a data set like below:

```
Timestamp                Value1   Value2
2020-10-29 05:00:00       10       20
2020-10-29 05:00:01       10       20
2020-10-29 05:00:02       11       22
2020-10-29 05:00:03       11       22
```

and so on, in one second intervals, and upto a few hours of data. I want to generate an average value two minutes, but left align the data. Essentially, rolling average of 2 minutes at `2020-10-29 05:00:00` should be the average of data points between `2020-10-29 05:00:00` and `2020-10-29 05:01:59`
I have used `data %>% group_by(Timestamp =cut (Timestamp, breaks="2min"))%>% summarize(Meanval1=mean(Value1), Meanval2=mean(Value2)` but this right aligns the data. How can I left align it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can round down the `Timestamp` column to the nearest two minutes using `lubridate::floor_date`. If you then `group_by` this new column, you will get a left-aligned two-minute mean:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(time = lubridate::floor_date(df$TimeStamp, "2 minutes")) %>%
  group_by(time) %>%
  summarize(mean_val1 = mean(Value1), mean_val2 = mean(Value2))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   time                mean_val1 mean_val2
#>   <dttm>                  <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 2020-10-29 05:00:00     10.2       19.9
#> 2 2020-10-29 05:02:00      9.84      20.0
#> 3 2020-10-29 05:04:00     10.1       19.9
#> 4 2020-10-29 05:06:00      9.72      20.3
#> 5 2020-10-29 05:08:00      9.98      19.9
#> 6 2020-10-29 05:10:00      9.98      20.0
#> 7 2020-10-29 05:12:00     10.1       20.0
#> 8 2020-10-29 05:14:00     10.0       20.1
#> 9 2020-10-29 05:16:00     10.0       20.2
```

**Data used**

```r
set.seed(69)
t  <- seq(as.POSIXct("2020-10-29 05:00:00"), by = "1 sec", length.out = 1000)
df <- data.frame(TimeStamp = t, 
                 Value1 = sample(8:12, 1000, TRUE), 
                 Value2 = sample(18:22, 1000, TRUE))

head(df)
#>             TimeStamp Value1 Value2
#> 1 2020-10-29 05:00:00      8     20
#> 2 2020-10-29 05:00:01     10     21
#> 3 2020-10-29 05:00:02      9     19
#> 4 2020-10-29 05:00:03     12     19
#> 5 2020-10-29 05:00:04     12     19
#> 6 2020-10-29 05:00:05      9     18
```